# What would create the triangles in this rock I found in the Lehigh River

Tags: rocks

I collect rocks from the Lehigh Valley River, I have found some many interesting rock. With details that could not be from the water. Can you tell me what would cause the 3 triangle indents on this
Rock.

[image]